# JS replace() returns ,,,,,,, instead of a number with a comma

Tags: javascript, function, replace, converters

the following code is a converter from euro to dollar in JS. It is a JS function. 
eingabe = input, ausgabe = output.
If I execute this code I get ,,,,,,,, as an output instead of 1,37.

```
eingabe = eingabe.replace(/,/g, ".");
eingabe = parseFloat(eingabe);
var kurs_euro = 1.37 // 1 euro = 1,37 dollar
var ausgabe = 0;
ausgabe = eingabe * kurs_euro;
ausgabe = Math.round((ausgabe + 0.00001) * 100)/100 + " Dollar";
ausgabe = ausgabe.toString();
ausgabe = ausgabe.replace(/./g, ",");
alert(ausgabe);
```

Comment: Don't use variable names in a different language from the one used in the programming language (it significantly lessens readability for all parts). Javascript is English-based, use English names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/./` means that you use regex and `.` replaces any character. Try without regex:

```
ausgabe.replace('.', ',');
```

Or escape `.`:

```
ausgabe.replace(/\./g, ',');
```

Comment: For multiple replace ausgabe.replace(new RegExp('.', 'g'), ','); can be used

Comment: @Ankur Thank you. I still do not understand your answer because I just started with JS but I will keep that in mind if I were to use multiple replaces.

hsz, Thank you :) just a missing escape... I will have to read up on regex

Comment: @Takeru It's the same that hsz did, with the difference that instead of using /\./g and escaping, I used javascript RegExp object to create a regular expression replacing dots globally in the string.